# Open in Twitter App Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, ios, twitter, bookmarklet

I have been trying to find a bookmarklet that will allow you to view a specific tweet in the twitter app. The API needed is `twitter://status?id=124556789012345789` and it will open tweet id 124556789012345789 which is found in the URL. I need to pull the tweet id from the URL and add it to the `twitter://status?id=`. The problem, is that the URL with the tweet id in it is `https://mobile.twitter.com/(username)/status/(tweet id)` and the username can vary. I tried to do `javascript:var s = (location.href);
var u = s.replace("https://mobile.twitter.com/*/status/", "twitter://status?id="));window.open(u);` but the * in the username didn't act as an unknow variable, as it sometimes does. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did making wild guesses work in Java? Did you learn Java efficiently by skipping over the most basic learning tasks?

Comment: actually, I'm still learning it and I never learns JavaScript. I taught it to myself and never had the time to formally learn it because I never would need it in the long run. I'm going to be a game programmer, and I only use JavaScript to make certain things easier. I come on to SO to try and get help, and instead I get flipped out on by another user. I thought this was a friendly community. apperently not.

Comment: "I'm going to be a game programmer" - I give you a 100% guarantee that one of these two things will happen in your future. A.) You will look back and realize that I was giving you very good advice (rude, but good), or... B.) You will not become a game programmer.

Comment: ok then. thank you for your advice, and I apologize. now, can you please help me with my original question?

Comment: I did that and the undefined isn't like a variable I can have in a string to be as like "ignore this; it doesn't matter what the value of the username is"

Comment: Correct. So you have to use a different approach. Look at the other string functions (not only `replace`) and ask yourself how you could use them to solve your problem. The closest thing to doing what you want and also do it in a way similar to what you were trying, but not very similar, is to use a regular expression in the `replace`, but that is a bit advanced and I don't recommend it for beginners. Look at the `split` function.

Comment: you have a bunch of unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: oh whoops. well at least the code works. here's a better working version: javascript:var a = (location.href); var b = a.split("/"); var c = b[5].replace("?photo=1",""); var d = ('twitter://status?id='+c); window.location = (d);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tada! `javascript:var a = (location.href); var b = a.split("/"); var c = b[5].replace("?photo=1",""); var d = ('twitter://status?id='+c); window.location = (d);`